# Error - NaN al operar con matrices por el método Gauss Jordan

Tags: python

Buenas noches estimados compañeros, tengo un problema, estoy tratando de resolver ecuaciones en matrices por el método de Gauss-Jordan en python, el cual transforma en matriz identidad. El problema es que al compilar el algoritmo me sale como respuesta 'nan' en vez de números. Les muestro el codigo y por favor espero que me puedan ayudar. Gracias!

```
    def gaussjordan1(a,b):
       n=len(b)
       c=np.concatenate([a,b],axis=1)
       for e in range(n):
           c[e,e:]=c[e,e:]/c[e,e]
           for i in range(n):
               if i!=e:
                   c[i,e:]=c[i,e:]-c[i,e]*c[e,e:]
       x=c[:,n]
       return x
   #Resolucion de ejemplo
   from numpy import*
   from gaussjordan1 import*
   a=array([[1,1,-1],[3,3,1],[1,0,1]],float)
   b=array([[2],[2],[0]],float)
   print (a)
   print("======================================")
   print(b)
   print("======================================")
   x=gaussjordan1(a,b)
   print("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")
   print(x)
   print("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")
```

Comment: Los.valorrs nan se produce en la tercera iteracion del ciclo, cuando intentas dividir entre 0, lo que provoca un error

Comment: El error se produce por dividir entre 0

Comment: Puedes ver este [codigo](https://replit.com/@nakato156/ajudaPERU-1#main.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cabe mencionar que no sé nada de matríces pero transcribí tu código por curiosidad y corriguiendo algunos parámetros en que me mostraba errores al ejecutar (los explíco con los  #) , finalmente quedó así :

```
def GaussJordan1(a,b):   # gaussjordan1 ---> GaussJordan1
    n=len(b)
    c=np.concatenate([a,b],axis=1)
    for e in range(n):
        c[e,e:]=c[e,e:]/c[e,e]
    for i in range(n):
        if i!=e:
            c[i,e:]=c[i,e:]-c[i,e]*c[e,e:]
            x=c[:,n]
            return x
   #Resolucion de ejemplo
   # from numpy import *
   # from gaussjordan1 import *
import numpy as np            

a= np.array([[1,1,-1],[3,3,1],[1,0,1]],float)  # a = array() --> a = np.array()
b= np.array([[2],[2],[0]],float)               # b = array() --> b = np.array()
print (a)
print("======================================")
print(b)
print("======================================")
x=GaussJordan1(a,b)  # x = gaussjordan1() --> x = GaussJordan1()
print("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")
print(x)
print("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")
```

y el resultado me mostró algo parecído a esto :

```
[[1. 1. -1.]
 [3. 3.  1.]
 [1. 0.  1.]]
======================
[[2.]
 [2.]
 [0.]]
======================
000000000000000000000000000000
[2.      0.6666667 0    ]
000000000000000000000000000000
```

espero te sírva de ayuda.

Comment: Tu codigo solo retorna el valor si `i != e` y no continúa iterando

Comment: Muchas gracias!, sí me sirvió

Comment: me alegro te haya servído , saludos!